# python: comparing values string/integer

Tags: python

i will be comparing two values like this:\

```
value1>value2
```

i know that value2 is always an integer, but sometimes value1 is None or a string, how do force the comparison ONLY if value1 is numerical?

**value1 is a decimal**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if value1:
    Decimal(value1) > value2
```

Comment: can you use this on a decimal also?

Comment: The `int` cast won't work pleasantly on a decimal. And the `isdigit()` only works on strings. You can check for the existance of `isdigit` with `hasattr` and change the `int` to `Decimal` to make sure you can compare both ints and Decimals.

Comment: will isdigit return true on 1.123?

Comment: As I said, that only works for strings. However, if your input is sanitized (all the strings can be casted to `Decimal`) than you can do with a simple `if value1` and a `Decimal(value1) > value2`

Answer (score 2):

#### Python 3

```
try:
    value1 > value2
except TypeError:
    pass
```

#### Python <3

```
if isinstance( value2, int ):
    value1 > value2
```

This latter is unpythonic, because this type of comparison is unpythonic. You should filter your data first.

Comment: can you use this on a decimal also?

Comment: Yes. The former because Py3k won't let you compare distinct types, and the latter because we *only* allow `int`s. You should try and think a bit about what the code is doing before asking such simple questions.

Answer (score 2):

```
try:
    int(value1) > value2
except (TypeError, ValueError):
    pass
```

Comment: can you use this on a decimal also?

Comment: Yes, you can.  Those two exceptions are raise when trying convert None or another object which can't be coerced to an int.  A float (1.23) can be coerced, so not exception will be raised.